# Show only one page link in content pagination

Tags: posts, navigation, content

Im currently using the  wp_link_pages tag to show the pagination links for content that is split inside the Post. Is there a way to show only the next page link and not all page number links or not show next & previous links? I just want to show only one next page link

Comment: are you using the main query or a custom one?

Answer (score 0):

To show prev/next links rather than numbered pagination you need to set the `next_or_number` argument to `next`.

Then if you want to remove the `previous` links, you can filter the HTML for the links with the `wp_link_pages` filter.

But, you can be craftier and filter on the `wp_link_pages_link` hook.

Although it is used in a number of contexts, when it is called for the `previous` link it passes a value representing the page number of the previous page.  If you check this against the global `$pages`, you can come up with the right logic to decide whether you are filtering a "previous" link rather than "next" or numbered pagination.

```
add_filter( 'wp_link_pages_link', 'wpse_235716_kill_previous', 10, 2);

function wpse_235716_kill_previous( $link, $prev ) {

    global $page;

    if ( $prev > 0 && $prev > $page ) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return $link;
    }

}
```

Comment: your filter doesn't work it does the opposite. It kills the next link instead of previous link